# Blender parent problem

Tags: parent

I used Blender2.79 and I think I just find the problem.

I have two objects and I want to make parent relations to each other,

when I used CTRL + P, the child's transform location still relate to the world's location.

[image]

However, when I manually use (properties -> object -> Relations: Parent) and select the object that I want to set it to parent. It used the parent's transform.

[image]

I belive those two ways are doing the same things and I miss the setting or this is a bug??

Comment: I just realize if I used (CTRL + SHIFT + P) and it can used parent's transform as world transform.

Answer (score 6):

This is from [wiki](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Pepribal/Ref/Appendices/ParentInverse):

> At the very moment of establishing a hierarchical relationship between
>   objects (parenting), the transformation coordinates of the child
>   object remain unchanged, and yet this object doesn't change its global
>   transforms visually (location, orientation or scale), though its
>   reference "world" has changed from global origin (zero transforms) to
>   the global transforms of the parent.
>
> Origin of unparented objects is the global origin: global (0,0,0)
>   location, zero rotation, and unity scale. After being parented, the
>   new origin should be that of the parent. And it is. But a correction
>   matrix is applied to the child, so that the new reference point is not
>   the global transforms of the parent, but the global origin. **This
>   correction matrix is applied** to the global transforms of the parent
>   before applying them to the child.

This correction matrix called **Parent Inverse**

You can do this operations with **Parent Inverse**:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> (clear origin) - this operation clears Parent Inverse and makes object go to the parent location.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> (Make parent without Inverse) - it's like what you do in properties -> object -> Relations: Parent. Or like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> Clear Parent Inverse in one comand

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> Clear Parent Inverse - Like <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> but for rotation and Scale.

Why Blender using Parent Inverse?

Let's try 2 objects  with Parent Inverse:

[image]

and without:

[image]

As you see, transform matrix, applied on parent object without inverse, makes child object distorted. If you want this effect - you are welcome, but mostly, we don't want it

Answer (score 0):

Select *Active Tool and Workspace Setting > Option > Transform > Uncheck Parents*