# difference between picker parent and ctrl-p parent?

Tags: parent

difference between picker parent and ctrl-p parent?

when I use the picker to parent the sphere object to cube the sphere moves from place of origin, but if I parent sphere to cube with ctrl-p, sphere does not move from place of origin.
why does that happen?

https://youtu.be/6glaRqeLQ0s

I use blender 2.79

Comment: See also   ... Oops meant to use  this one as dupe https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/94424/blender-parent-problem anyhow  Not sure if you are interested in [maths / code](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/169424/15543)  but former is keeping child in place by setting the parent inverse (by default) and latter isn't .. so if the child was at origin it is now at location of parent.