# Two objects right next to each other, but wildly different coordinates

Tags: parent, coordinates

Can someone explain why the coordinates on these two objects are so drastically different?

The Y direction, which is UP/DOWN in this view, should be the same between these two objects.  But they differ by 1000.

I figure that this must have something to do with the object that I have both of these objects parented to.  It is a reference which I sometimes move between location Y=0 and Y=1000.  Perhaps I added one object while the parent was at Y=0, and another when it was at Y=1000, but it seems like the coordinates should change when the parent does, or they should remain fixed to the parent's coordinate system.  But this is just...baffling.

How do I fix this?

[image: Object A]

[image: Object B]

EDIT:
Here is a simple blend file showing the issue.
The cubes are named "Parent", "Child 1", and "Child 2".

They all started out on the X axis, 5 meters apart.

I parented "Child 1" to Parent.

Then I move Parent and Child 2 up by 10 meters on the Y axis.  Child 1 followed along, because it's parented to Parent 1.

I then parented Child 2 to Parent.

Now when you click on Child 1, the Y coord is 0.  On Child 2, the Y coord is 10.

[image]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/169416/does-a-child-object-inherit-the-matrix-from-the-parent  The basis matrix properties are shown in the UI.  The default parenting mode in blender sets the parent inverse to keep the basis the same, so if you unparent the object it keeps its basis. If you parent in the object properties relations panel it doesn't set the inverse, which leads to more "understandable" UI coords. An object at origin when parented this way moves to the transform of its parent.  There are a number of Qs re this, will try and track some down.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blender parent problem](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/94424/blender-parent-problem)   This script will sanitize the child coords https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28896/how-to-clear-parent-inverse-without-actually-moving-the-object